Unit testing with Jest is ignoring exception throwing in RxJS observables
I have a parent and child class structure. In some scenarios the child notifies the parent when a value changes, so the parent can react.
Child.ts
class Child {
  public id: string;
  private _value: string;
  private _valueChangeNotifier = new Subject<string>();

  get onValueChange$() {
    return this._valueChangeNotifier.asObservable();
  } 

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(newValue: string) {
    this._value = newValue;
    this.notifyChangeOfValue();
  }

  private notifyChangeOfValue() {
    this._valueChangeNotifier.next(this._value);
  }

}

Parent.ts
class Parent {
  private _children: Child[];

  constructor(parentSetup: any) {
    for (const childSetup of parentSetup.childrenSetup) {
      const child = ChildBuilder.create(childSetup);
      child.onValueChange$
        .pipe(
          tap(newValue => this.throwErrorIfTheNewValueHasSomethingWrong(newValue))
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (newValue => this.transformValueForAFutureGenerationOfOutput(newValue))
        })
    }
  }

  private throwErrorIfTheNewValueHasSomethingWrong(newValue: string) {
    /* 
      ...doing some validations and throwing an exception if any validation fails
    */
  }

  getChildById(id: string) {
    return this._children.find(child => child.id === id);
  }
}

UnitTestWithJest.ts
it('should test a method of the parent who needs the child to have value', () => {
    /*
      const parent = ...some parent initialization methods
    */

    // At this point I expected some validation exception to be thrown, but Jest simply ignores it
    parent.getChildById('<CHILD_UUID>').value = 'Any value that fails parent validation'; 
    const output = parent.generateSomeOutputBasedOnChildrenAndTheirValues();
    
    /* 
      Validation failed because some child value did not have the expected value, 
      so the method that transforms the data was not called, so the output does not match what was expected. 
      Therefore, the exception was thrown "internally", but Jest did not catch it.
    */ 
     expect(output).toMatchObject({ ...myExpectedOutput }); 
});

To make sure the exception was being thrown, I even implemented the observer's error handling method.
Parent.ts
  constructor(parentSetup: any) {
    for (const childSetup of parentSetup.childrenSetup) {
      const child = ChildBuilder.make(childSetup);
      child.onValueChange$
        .pipe(
          tap(newValue => this.throwErrorIfTheNewValueHasSomethingWrong(newValue))
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (newValue => this.transformValueForAFutureGenerationOfOutput(newValue)),
          error: (error) => console.error(error) /* <- Added error handling */
        })
    }
  }

Jest prints the error correctly as expected, but it still ignores it and instead of pausing the test execution, it simply says that the unit test failed as if no exception was thrown.
I don't understand why Jest is ignoring the error like this. I have in my mind that the execution should be interrupted with the exception thrown by the validations.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to make Jest "not ignore" the error and stop execution because of the exception thrown?
Note: The intention of the test is not to test whether the parent is throwing an exception or not. The intention is to verify whether the output at the end is as expected. I accidentally fell into this "bug" by passing a value to the child that I believed was correct (when in fact it was not), and Jest simply failed without throwing the exception. When I realized that I had passed the wrong value and Jest ignored the exception, I thought it was strange and started investigating further, but I could not find the cause.
Note 2: I didn't write an error handler in the parent, because I want the error to be propagated upwards.
